# How to use tuio to invoke a listener for a button?

Tags: java, multi-touch

I am kind of confusing about the listener for a button when do the touch-table app using Tuio.
I think I need the listener like ActionListener() for button in the Tuio listeners.

Could you guys give me some ideas?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add TuioListener to the Tuio Client after do Implements tuioListener [when you declare your class]

```
*client = new TuioClient();
client.addTuioListener(this);
client.connect();*
```

Then, tuio is always listening to every touch.

Then you have to check in tuioCursor methods (add, update, remove) what component you just touched [usually, actions are done when you remove cursor]

Assuming the jButton has its Action already assigned, the code is relatively simple. You find the point you've touched, get the component touched, check if it's a jButton, cast component to jButton and it does its action.

```
*public void removeTuioCursor(TuioCursor tc) {

int posX = tc.getScreenX((int) this.getSize().getWidth());
int posY = tc.getScreenY((int) this.getSize().getHeight());

  Component comp = this.getComponentAt(posX, posY);
  if (comp != null) {
     JButton boton = new JButton();
     if (comp.getClass().equals(boton.getClass())) {
        boton = (JButton) comp;
        boton.doClick();
     }
  }
}*
```